# Please how do I sort map elements based on values in ascending order in java?

Tags: java, sorting, linkedhashmap

I am trying to sort map elements (based on values) by using Collections.sort(). The problem is that my program sorts the elements in descending order instead of sorting it in ascending order. How can I sort it in ascending order? Below is my code.

```
package hashTableRR;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
public class OrderByValue {

    public static void main(String [] args){

    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    map.put(1, 4);
    map.put(2, 6);
    map.put(3, 1);
    map.put(4, 1);
    map.put(6, 8);
    map.put(7, 5);

    Set<Entry<Integer, Integer>> set = map.entrySet();
    List<Entry<Integer, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Entry<Integer, Integer>>(set);
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>()
    {
        public int compare(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> o2){
            return(o2.getValue()).compareTo(o1.getValue());
        }
    }

            );

    System.out.println("Keys\t\tValues");
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry:list)
    {
        System.out.println(" "+entry.getKey()+"\t\t  "+entry.getValue());

    }       


    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `return(o1.getValue()).compareTo(o2.getValue());`. Please note that compare order matters.

Comment: Thank you all so much, it worked!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values-java)

Answer (score 3):

Just change the order of variables in your `compare` function

```
return(o1.getValue()).compareTo(o2.getValue());
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely in your `Comparator#compare` implementation.

You are returning: `o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue())`

For an ascending order, you should return: `o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue())`

This will generate a negative value if `o1 < o2`, `0` if they're equal and a positive value if `o2 > o1`.

See slightly cryptical documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-).

---

Here's an insight of what values you can expect your `Comparator` to return when performing a comparison of `Integer`s in Java (full doc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compareTo-java.lang.Integer-)):

> the value 0 if this Integer is equal to the argument Integer; a value less than 0 if this Integer is numerically less than the argument Integer; and a value greater than 0 if this Integer is numerically greater than the argument Integer (signed comparison).

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help, all of you.

Answer (score 1):

Just use :

```
return(o1.getValue()).compareTo(o2.getValue());
```

It will obviously inverse order

Answer (score 1):

```
 Map<Integer, Integer> unsortedMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    unsortedMap.put(1, 4);
    unsortedMap.put(2, 6);
    unsortedMap.put(3, 1);
    unsortedMap.put(4, 1);
    unsortedMap.put(6, 8);
    unsortedMap.put(7, 5);


    unsortedMap.entrySet().
            stream().
            sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed()).
            forEachOrdered(x -> sortedMap.put(x.getKey(), x.getValue()));

    System.out.println(sortedMap);
```

> > Use `LinkedHashMap` if you want to store your data in the order in which keys are inserted into the `Map`. 
> >     `HashMap` doesn't guarantee any order.